# Origins of gender distinction in verbs in Slavic

Tags: morphology, verbs, indo-european, gender, slavic-languages

This is a thing that I have been thinking about for a while. I know that PIE did not have gender distinction in verb forms, and its presence in modern Slavic languages must be an innovation.

If I am correct this phenomenon occurs exclusively in the Slavic family (I still have in mind only IE languages). My questions are:

- What is the probable origin of it, how did it develop within the Slavic group ?
- Do any IE families or languages besides Slavic contrast between masculine and feminine verbs forms, even in the slightest degree ?
- Are there any universal lingustic processes that may lead to that ?

I want to emphasize that I am only concerned about the **verb**.

Of course any references to articles, books etc. will be very welcome.

Comment: I can't say anything about Slavic languages, but often enough a gender-inflected participle will show up in a periphrastic verbal construction and require gender agreement with something, usually a subject. In Latin, for instance, the passive perfect forms of most verbs are periphrastic and involve participles with _esse_. This is how the perfect tense in Hindi developed its ergative character, because it originally was a periphrastic construction.

Comment: Grammatical gender (GG) is a property of a **noun**, not of a verb. GG of verbs [do agree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29#Gender) with nouns, so for most languages having GG it has little sense to research a verb's GG with no conjunction with the associated noun. There are controversial hypotheses about the origin of inflected forms, one of those is that the **bound morphemes** (e.g. endings) originally used to be free morphemes, but became agglutinated during the course of language's development.

Comment: Until I read these answers I just didn't realise that the past polish verb forms are etymologically participles, hence the gender distinction. Now it is all clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slavic verbs in past tense are simply periphrastic participle constructions.

*Našel jsem* literally (etymologically) means "the-one-who-found-it I-am". And as any normal particple, it agrees in gender with subject. In Russian, the copula is omitted usually; in Polish, it was fused with the verb (suffix -em for 1p sg.), in languages like Czech or Serbian, the copula is still there. In the languages I know (for example, Russian) L-participles are not an active language feature anymore (not used independently), however some of them were moved to the category of adjectives and can be used independently: e.g. Russian *gniloj* "rotten" which is now an adjective as opposed to the "real deal", the real participle (in the modern language), *sgnivšij* with a different suffix.

So it's not something unusual. If I'm not mistaken, French "Passé composé" dinstinguishes genders as well: *Je suis montée* vs. *Je suis monté* etc., because etymologically, it's the same thing.

Comment: Right. Just a comment about the history: verbs have almost certainly been gender-dependent in Slavic languages from the very beginning. However, it's true that there's some evolution. For example, transgressives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transgressive_(linguistics) are forms of infinitives or participles that used to be common in Czech/Slovak but have largely disappeared. The transgressives are past ("having sat down" as one word) or present ("[while] seeing", one word) and gender-dependent although the gender forms differ "less" than the surviving main forms of verbs.

Answer (score 1):

In some Iranian languages (maybe Indic as well), the past tense construction involves a verb that is etymologically a passive participle, agreeing in gender with the verb's object rather than its subject: e.g.,

Pashto *mā xǝz**a** lidǝl**a*** "I saw a/the woman"

The literal translation of this sentence would be something like "the woman was-seen by-me", since the pronoun *mā* is an oblique 1sg. pronoun, the nominative form being *zǝ*.

Comment: Isn't it a part of something called partial ergativity ?
If I remember correctly there was a development of a special syntactic structure in passive past tense. I think that modern Hindustani also shares that phenomenon.

Comment: Maybe so. I'm not an expert, but from what I have read, this phenomenon only occurs in the past tense: present-tense verbs in Pashto agree with their subject and are not inflected for gender.

Comment: It developed from a stylistic custom in old indo-iranian languages of putting the subject and object in different syntactical patterns in past tense than it would be usually done in present.
Anyways, as I stated before, I have to check again, I might have confused something.